# Replace a value between stings [ url parameter ] in different conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to modify url values based on some condition

(1)If my current url is `http://example.com`

then i have to add **?order=new** to the url  for this i write the following code and it is working

```
var url=window.location.href;
       url=url+"order=new";
```

(2)If my current url is `http://example.com/?class=1`
then i have to add **&order=new** to the url  for this i write the following code and it is working

```
var url=window.location.href;
    if(url.indexOf("class=") >= 0){
        url=url+"&order=new";
    }
```

(3)If my current url is `http://example.com/?class=1&order=new` 
    then i have to add **&order=date** to the url  for this i write the following code and it is working

```
 var url=window.location.href;
   if (url.indexOf("order=") >=0){
        url= url.split("order=")[0]+"order=date";
                }
```

(4)     If my curent url is `http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&div=anyvalue&order=anyvalue`    or `http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&order=anyvalue&div=anyvalue`. Here how can i replace order value ?

ie

```
 http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&div=anyvalue&order=anything
 http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&order=anything&div=anyvalue
```

Please support

Comment: replace order with what?

Comment: if  http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&div=anyvalue&order=123
 then    http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&div=anyvalue&order=456

Comment: you want to add `order=new` and `order=date`? Only one value can be there for a key! You need to change the names of the key

Comment: that i know . now i want to add order=new only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```
var url = window.location.href;
var urlObj = new URL( url );
```

Now you can search parameters of the URL

```
var order = urlObj.searchParams.get("order");
if ( !order )
{
   //url +=  url.contains( "?" ) ? "&order=new" : "?order=new";
   //contains didnt work so used includes instead
   url +=  url.includes( "?" ) ? "&order=new" : "?order=new";  
}
```

Similarly, you can replace value as well

```
var order = urlObj.searchParams.get("order");
if ( order )
{
   urlObj.searchParams.set("order", "123");
}
console.log( urlObj.href );
```

Update:
added jsfiddle to your solution :)...
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/n274q78r/)

Comment: no , because i confused . could you please look bipen solution and the comment i wrote for that solution

Comment: This is a good solution. I had no idea of `new URL()` object. +1.

Comment: @gurvinder372 added fiddle link

Comment: @abilasher Check you console for output. Replace the string in `set()` with whatever you need

Comment: after  urlObj.searchParams.set("order", "123"); how can i save this url to a variable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160906/discussion-between-abilash-er-and-bipen).

Comment: @bipen Thanks for adding the fiddle

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can say, I think you want this:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&order=anything&div=anyvalue';
if (url.indexOf("order=") >= 0 && url.indexOf('div=') >= 0){
    newUrl = url.replace('order=anything', 'order=456');
}
```

using `replace()` function. Change the `url` to what you are using.

Comment: but here is the probelm http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&order=anything&div=anyvalue   here anyvalue  is random value or random text .  Example http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&order=123&div=anyvalue  or http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&order=sample&div=anyvalue or http://example.com/?class=anyvalue&order=543&div=anyvalue

Comment: hi do you understand what i mean ?

Comment: @abilasher the above solution is good and reliable. My way is simplest. Let me add solution there.

Comment: Cool. Happy coding. For other user this is not the solution the one above is :). Helped him to figure it out

Comment: you are good. Thanks for the help . It's because of my question is not clear that's why the problem come .